# Fetching results from MySQL InnoDB database [XAMPP] with PHP takes a lot longer on my computer than on those of others

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm working in a team on a project that involves a huge database (24481 rows). When loading/displaying all of these at once through a PHP search function it takes about 10 seconds on my device while it goes almost instantly on that of the others.

This confuses me a lot since we use the same version of PHPMyAdmin, use the exact same database and application, and I definitely don't have a slow computer (XAMPP is even installed on my SSD).

Any ideas as to why this loading the results takes so much longer on my PC?

Comment: Are you accessing the same database server instance across a network connection or do each of you have a copy of the database stored and accessed locally?

Comment: Locally in PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

No issues.. This actually depends on a lot of factors. 
Like available memory, 
Your CPU. etc.

So,just don't bother about this once you deploy it on the server it will work fine.

However as a quick workaround turn on `mysql_query_caching` to get the results faster, and build `indexes` .